# SPN : Delegated permission

Tags: azure, api

I'm new to API/SPN, sorry if my question seems trivial...
If an SPN has, for example, the MS Graph IMAP.AccessAsUser.All right and is of type "Delegated".
If the user who is connecting has the IMAP Protocol disabled on their mailbox, will IMAP still work from the SPN?
Same question with the type "Application".

In other words, do the permissions of the SPN "override" others?

Thank you